# nextJs how to stop audio from playing when route changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I only want the audio to play on the route that loads this component, when the route loads the audio does start to play, but when I navigate to a different page it keeps playing?? I don't get it!

I've tried setting up event listeners for `beforeunload` and `routeChangeStart`

```
import { useEffect, FunctionComponent, useRef } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export interface PropsShape {
  audioSrc: string;
}

const AudioPlayer: FunctionComponent<PropsShape> = ({ audioSrc }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(audioSrc));
  audioRef.current.play();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowClose = (): void => {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    };
    const handleBrowseAway = (): void => {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    };
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleBrowseAway);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleBrowseAway);
    };
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
};

export default AudioPlayer;
```

I'm using "next": "12.1.0",

Comment: Idk if this is your issue but `audioRef.current.play();` should be inside your `useEffect` hook, so it's only called when the component mounts and not every rerender. Since both callbacks do the same thing you can use the same pause function on both event listeners.  Also, you can `return null` instead of an empty `div`.